# how to add a methyl group to a straight carbon chain

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

I mean like how can I convert ethane into propane, ethene into propene and like this further on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Direct ethene to propene (ETP) conversion seems [possible](http://dx.doi.org/10.3390/molecules16097844) at 400 °C on mesoporous silica (M41) loaded with nickel ions.

Comment: Note that I didn't know that either until now and just found it in a cursory search!

Answer (score 2):

Why would you want an expensive process to convert cheap molecules into other cheap molecules?  Brominate ethane, make the organo-lithium, displace methyl iodide. Epoxidize ethylene, react with methyl lithium, eliminate to the olefin. Silly.

Doing something cheap, easy, and fast on a huge scale with unwanted methane from oil wells to form a high energy density liquid for pipeline conveyance will make you rich. Methanol is marginal - and still can't be done.  Perhaps methane plus air into titanium-silicalite (plus hydrogen peroxide, or cobalt- or vanadium-doped plus air) then that mixed product through ZSM-5 into aromatic gasoline.  That could be exciting in various ways.

http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.apcata.2008.04.020 
http://chemelab.ucsd.edu/methanol/memos/final.html

Comment: Because I am in high school and I have to it on paper not in reality, this is on of the higher order thinking skills question that my school have to me.

Comment: A. M. Schwartz, M. Petitjean, "[6.6]Chiralane: a remarkably symmetric chiral molecule," Symmetry: Culture and Science 19(4) 307-316 (2008). It is a molecule whose sense of chirality cannot be named, even in principle, http://www.mazepath.com/uncleal/schwart3.png  When CAS and Agnew Chemie cannot name a bunch of chiral centers, I say "publish it."  They said "no."  It does not impact my income.

Comment: Folks, I know you were likely just joking with each other, but someone reading your comments later might misconstrue them.

Comment: Who reads organic chemistry? "8^>) Employment is EPA-expelled offshore. September 1969, Michigan State, 1200+ Majors Organic enrollment. June 1973, 15 BS/Chem graduated.  Wanting it more than anything else is a good start.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you cant go ethane to propene, it should be propane.

Chemically, you can do it by following steps:

1. halogenate with $\ce{Cl}$ in UV.
2. then use $\ce{KCN}$ to make nitrile - it will replace $\ce{Cl}$.
3. hydrolyse it using $\ce{KOH}$.
4. then it will be a carboxylic acid.
5. reduce it using $\ce{LiAlH4}$ and then, you have got propane.

You can go for ethene the same way, but there will be complications.

Comment: You haven't really done that, have you?  Photochlorination of ethane will yield ethylchloride (btw suspect of being _cancerogenic_) plus butane (from the termination step of the radical reaction) plus chlorinated butane(s).  $S_N1$ reactions of alkyl chlorides with sodium or potassium cyanide in DMSO do work in principle. Here, the boiling point of ethylchloride is 12 °C, the melting point of DMSO is 19 °C.   Propionitrile to propionic acid looks ok, but what about the reduction?  The reaction of propionic acid with $\ce{LiAlH4}$ will yield 1-propanol.